# XML -> XSL -> HTML edit file, and SAVE changes in xml WITHOUT asp

Tags: html, xml, xslt, asp-classic, save

I have an XML file that I've transformed with xsl and loaded into a browser as html. That html is editable using a rich text editor by the user. When they're done I need to transform their html edits back to the original xml document.

One solution I've found is using ASP: http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_editxml.asp

But I'm using Apache and I don't have ASP installed, and I'm wondering if there is an easier/better way to do this without using ASP.

Or is ASP the only way?

Thanks =)

Comment: Choose another language? PHP?

Comment: Can I save changes from html to xml using php? It would have to convert a href tags to xref per my .xsl file

Answer (score 1):

The solutiton that you found doesn't do what you describe. It only presents the data from the XML as a form, and lets the user edit the values. That's not very complex, and you can do that using pretty much any other server side language, like PHP for example.

What you describe, on the other hand, is quite complex. It involves examining the XSL and the HTML to identify the parts of the HTML code that was created using specific XML data, so that changes can be reflected back. That's not something that is done with a simple ASP script like that.

Comment: Oh I see..you're right I misunderstood what the example did. I already have it editing the fields in the form. So when they do edit it, and I want to save it back to xml, it's more complex than I thought..but on one hand I'm restricted to mainly converting html tags to xml. How should I tackle this then? Go through and look at each individual tag with the case of a href, and change it to xref, etc?

Answer (score 0):

If you design an XSL transformation for both directions, XML to HTML and HTML to XML, comparing the source XML and resulting user XML should be a much easier problem to solve.